# One spouse in community property state, other spouse in non-community property state, filing taxes jointly

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, state-income-tax

I am a resident of California, a community-property state, earning my income in California. My wife is a resident of Oregon, a non-community-property state, earning her income in Oregon. We file taxes jointly. My questions are:

1. Is half of my California income considered her income, and thus is subject to Oregon tax (since she's an Oregon resident)? If so, that half of my California income would be taxed in both Oregon and California (since it's California-source income), so do we pay the tax on it in California and get a tax credit for it in Oregon, or do we pay the tax for it in Oregon and get a tax credit for it in California?
2. Is half of my wife's Oregon income considered my income, and thus is subject to California tax (since I'm a California resident)? If so, that half of her Oregon income would be taxed in both California and Oregon (since it's Oregon-source income), so do we pay the tax on it in California and get a tax credit for it in Oregon, or do we pay the tax for it in Oregon and get a tax credit for it in California?

Comment: This seems like a question for a tax professional. Honestly I would just do my taxes on one of the websites and see what it says.... After filing I probably still wouldn't know exactly :p